# How do i correctly match a List of Strings?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I am attempting to set up a when statement for a method used inside another method I am testing. Inside the method I am testing I am creating a list which I have no reference to, therefore I cannot mock it. I would like to validate the contents of this list when it is used in the above mentioned method inside. I have used the following as part of the when method, but ended up with an "InvalidUseOfMatchersException" in every case. What am I missing?

```
Matchers.eq(mockKeys) //mockKeys is a List<String> with expected contents
Matchers.anyListOf(String.class)

Mockito.when(myDaoImpl.getRecords([either of the above])).thenReturn(mockResult);
```

I must refuse to provide exact code.

Comment: You don't have to provide your original code, but you'll have to provide more than this.  This isn't mocking... it's matching... I'm confused.

Comment: Where is your `Mockito` stuff (objects, stubs, verifications)?

Comment: Made edit to include example.

Comment: If it helps, the mockKeys list will be equal to a list that is generated inside the method and eventually consumed by the myDaoImpl method.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> mockKeys = createMockKeys(); // defined elsewhere
when(myDaoImpl.getRecords(Matchers.eq(mockKeys))).thenReturn(mockResult);
when(myDaoImpl.getRecords(mockKeys)).thenReturn(mockResult); // implicitly equal
when(myDaoImpl.getRecords(Matchers.anyListOf(String.class)))
    .thenReturn(mockResult);
```

All of the above are fine. Nothing you've posted looks inherently wrong; it's more likely a problem we can't see, such as if `getRecords` is final, or in a use of Mockito or Matchers surrounding your code. Though it is understandable not to be able to post more code than you can, it may make it hard to provide a more-specific answer.

For the sake of debugging, place a call to [`Mockito.validateMockitoUsage()`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#validateMockitoUsage%28%29) before and after your stub. This will help ensure that the problem is actually on the line you think it is, and not pollution from calls before or after.

Comment: I have verified it is the issue. I get a null pointer do to the output of the DaoImpl method being null.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the two lines `Matchers.eq(mockKeys);` and `Matchers.anyListOf(String.class)`.  As the message says, you're using them invalidly.

Mockito uses its own data structure to store a matcher when you call such a method, but returns a different value from the actual call.  That additional value must be passed to the method that you're stubbing (`getRecords` in this case), and when you stub, Mockito retrieves the actual matchers from the data structure.

Unless you completely understand how the data structure works, and know *exactly* what you're doing, you really need to put the calls to the two `Matchers` methods inside the call to `getRecords`.  For example,

```
when(myDaoImpl.getRecords(eq(mockKeys), anyListOf(String.class))).thenReturn(mockResult);
```

Comment: Attempted this and it does not work. It does not match any of the methods involved...

Comment: Then your problem must be something else.  You'll need to post your code if you want us to find it for you.